# Помощь по checkbox

Tags: html, css, checkbox

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть где-нибудь информация по тому как делать такие checkbox`ы?

Answer (score 3):

Самый простой вариант - скрывать чекбоксы и стилизовать лейблы к ним:

```css
input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: silver;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#design:checked ~ label[for="design"],
#verstka:checked ~ label[for="verstka"],
#razrabotka:checked ~ label[for="razrabotka"]{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="design" />
<label for="design">Дизайн</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="verstka" />
<label for="verstka">Верстка</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="razrabotka" />
<label for="razrabotka">Разработка</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Да есть. https://bootsnipp.com/tags/checkbox и для понимания https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/. Это самый "простой" и "красивый" вариант на мой взгляд